# Created scala docker image using sbt native plugin. I have to add LDAP CA cert. How to add that in the image

Tags: scala, docker, ldap, sbt-native-packager

Scala docker plug in creates the docket image but how to add LDAP CA certificate in the image. Is there any property to set the LDAP certificate. My application requires ldap authentication during login

Comment: If you have CA certificate files. `COPY /local/ca-certificates /docker/ca-certficate/location`

Comment: I am using plug in which creates new dockerfile when ever i user docker:publishlocal .So point is how to add this entry through plugin so that it should not be overriden

Answer (score 1):

i achieved it by

```
dockerCommands+=Cmd("USER", "root")
```

dockerCommands += Cmd("RUN" ,"apk update  && apk add openssl")
dockerCommands += Cmd("RUN" ,"apk add --no-cache curl")
dockerCommands += Cmd("RUN" ,"curl http://crl.xyz.com/xCertBundle.p7b | openssl pkcs7 -
print_certs -outform PEM -out CertBundle.pem")
dockerCommands+= Cmd("RUN" , "keytool -importcert -noprompt -alias 'xyzBundle' -file
CertBundle.pem -storepass changeit -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-
openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts")

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a mapping for your certificate file:

https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats/universal.html#universal-plugin-getting-started-with-packaging